# $.fieldValue is not a function alert on login form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, authentication, drupal-7

In D7, with Devel, CTools and [Ajax Login/Register plugins](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_register), I get an alert on submitting the login form on: http://p262957.mittwaldserver.info/drupal/user/login

I#m using a custom child theme based on bootstrap project. I already tried the instructions herein https://www.drupal.org/node/1008664 that say that I should asure loading jquery.form.js before ajax.js.

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks in advance.

I have nothing login specific coded so far except in html.tpl.php:

```
<?php
   $form_element = drupal_get_form("user_login");
   $form = drupal_render($form_element);
   print $form;
?>
```

The rest comes from the plugins, especially Ajax Login/Register plugins.

Comment: Can you post relevant code?

Comment: Thanks, I've written no code for this excepting al little bit markup and the call of the form. I will add it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parent theme was a ajax.js override function that caused the error. It can be found in theme_root_dir/js/misc/. You just have to empty it. Don't forget to empty your cache afterwards. Now it should work.